# How to model a cylinder with a mouth, with quad topology

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, topology

I came across a FB Blender group, and saw this model which was made with an add-on, box cutter, or something alike. I'm trying to understand how this topology was made, but my result are not even close to it. I started off using the simple deform modifier and trying to rearrange the topology scaling and moving the mesh. But I'd like to see if someone can show me a better result to match the original shape/topology.

[image]

Comment: for me looks like you only need to add a bevel modifier and you should be very close ;)

Comment: Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this way: Create a 32 vertex cylinder, in *Edit* mode duplicate, rotate and *Face > Intersect (Boolean)*:

[image]

Clean up the topology and create some vertical loopcuts:

[image]

Create some horizontal edge loops with the *Knife* tool, select the faces and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*:

[image]

Rework the topology a bit, extrude the slot inwards:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, shade smooth:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do what's call a  Boolean 'Slice' operation, you need the addon Bool tools to be enabled. Its a free and comes with blender just need to enable it.

It works similar to regular booleans; and if I remember correctly the way it works is as a 'cut away' and only effects the intersecting region, so you are left with 2 meshes minus the 'dead region' (region that the original mesh intersection is not utilizing).